# Get doc function running multiple times in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Firebase for Authentication & Storage. I am using `useContext` from react to wrap my app in an authentication layer.

Once I get the user from the authentication layer I then make a call to Firestore to retrieve the users details. However, this function is being looped (called multiple times).

```
export default function Profile() {
  const { user, loading } = useContext(authContext);
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  // THIS FUNCTION IS BEING LOOPED
  const handleProfile = async () => {
    const userProfileRef = doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "user", user.uid);
    try {
      const userProfile = await getDoc(userProfileRef);
      setProfile(userProfile.data());
      console.log("SET USER DATA");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  if (!user && !loading) {
    router.push("/");
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col relative">
      {user &&
        !loading &&
        (handleProfile(),
        (
          <button
            onClick={() => setDropdownOpen((prev) => !prev)}
            className="flex items-center gap-2.5 focus:ring-0"
          >
            <Image
              placeholder="blue"
              alt="user profile"
              src={profile.image_URL}
              height={48}
              width={48}
              className="rounded-full bg-gray-400"
            />
            <div className="flex flex-col text-left">
              <p className="font-semibold">{profile.name}</p>
              <p className="text-gray-400 text-sm">{profile.email}</p>
            </div>
            {dropdownOpen ? (
              <FiChevronUp size={"20px"} color={"gray"} />
            ) : (
              <FiChevronDown size={"20px"} color={"gray"} />
            )}
          </button>
        ))}
      <div>{dropdownOpen && <UserDropdown />}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend moving handleProfile into a `useEffect` as it is just getting data from your firestore:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function handleProfile() {
      if(user.uid) {
        const userProfileRef = doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "user", user.uid);
        try {
          const userProfile = await getDoc(userProfileRef);
          setProfile(userProfile.data());
          console.log("SET USER DATA");
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    };

    handleProfile();
  }, [user]);
```

I would then also remove the `handleProfile()` call in your JSX.

If you are using NextJS I would also recommend looking into their solution for [data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching) (Will vary depending on your NextJS Version)

Comment: This resolves the issue of a loop, however, now the error is "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')"

Comment: The issue is that I am waiting for the AuthContext to return to me the user so I can pull the user.uid and then fetch the user info from the db, using the user.uid, i'm not sure that it could be a server component as I'm waiting for my AuthContext which must be a client component. Unless i'm wrong and completely missed something.

Comment: `user.uid` is null when the useEffect runs. Adding some checks that the uid exists would be wise. If the user context updates the useEffect will run again as we added `user` as a dependency in the array

Comment: I've wrapped it in if (user) {} which seems to have done the trick, could you just update your answer so I can mark as correct? cheers.

Comment: All done! Hope this helps.